# python cvxopt installation Mac

Tags: python, cvxopt

I have a Mac 10.6.8 with Pycharm 3.0.3 installed
When I install the cvxopt packege via terminal:

pip install cvxopt

and then i import the module I get the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/**init**.py", line 242, in 
    cvxopt.base.normal, cvxopt.base.uniform = normal, uniform
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'base'

I ve been trying several solution but no luck

Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you have python 3 this isnt working, you’re using the python 2 pip. To use the python 3 pip try pip3 install.